# Rewriting php urls to produce clean urls .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, content-management-system

I'm using a custom built CMS and I need to rewrite the urls because currently they take the page ID and name of the page into the url.

```
/pages/1411760825/Facilities is an example of the current url
/Facilities is what I want it to show up as in the URL bar
```

The pages are linking to each other based on their ids and titles and I want it to not do that anymore.

This is the current .htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.xml(.*) $1.php$2 [nocase]
```

I know I need to add a line below to rewrite what I want it to be, but I'm unsure how to achieve this.

Comment: If you enter `/Facilities` in your browser would it not be 404?

Comment: Yeah, that's what it does... but I want to make it so it accepts /Facilities as part of the URL

Comment: Its not clear. If `/Facilities` is the URL you want to show in browser then how will it find page id?

Comment: Is there a way to make it not be 404 using htaccess? or will I need to find a way to completely reconfigure the CMS to make the URLs what I want?